# C can't understand why the while loop does not work

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int GetPositiveInt();

int main(void)
{
    int height = GetPositiveInt();
    int i =0;
    int counter = 1;
    printf("height: %d \n" ,height );

    for (i = 0; i < height ; i++)
    {
        printf("#\n");
        counter++;
    }
}

int GetPositiveInt(void)
{
    int height ;
    do
    {
        printf("please enter a non negetive integer no greater than 23 \n  ");
        height = GetInt();
    }
    while (( height < 0 ) &&  (height > 24)  );

   return height;
}
```

Here, in function `GetPositiveInt`, I would expect the `do while` loop to work if I enter any number above 23 or below 1, and for some reason only the while loop for height `< 0` works.

Comment: " above 23 or below 1" the word `or` indicates, that you shall use `||`.

Comment: How do you think something can be **both** < 0  **and** > 24 *simultaneously* ? Think you want  `||` there; not `&&`.

Answer (score 2):

This line is logically incorrect:

```
while (( height < 0 ) &&  (height > 24)  );
```

Height cannot be both less than zero **and** greater than 24 so you need to use **or** operator:

```
while (( height < 1 ) ||  (height > 23)  ); // Height is less than 1 or greater than 23
```

Comment: Even with the `||` operator the OP's loop does nothing useful.

Answer (score 1):

> here i would expect the loop to work if i enter any number above 23 **or**
>   below 1

You need to change while loop condition as

```
while (( height < 1 ) ||  (height > 23)  ); //below 1 or above 23
```

So it will work.

Comment: If it should really be `above 23 or below 1` it should be `while ((height <= 0) || (height >= 24))`, I guess.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Yes same problem with the most upvoted answer above .

Comment: If the OP doesn't know about `||`, he or she might now know about `<=` and `>=` either. <g>

Comment: @RudyVelthuis corrected my answer is there any more suggestion?